# Calculate difference in hours between two date time values

Tags: scala, date

I have a date time string `yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm` with the value `2016-JAN-17 12:23`, and I need to check if the difference between current time and this date time string is greater than 5 hours. If it's greater, then the value of variable `is_greater` should be equal to 1, otherwise 0.

```
val datetimestring = "2016-JAN-17 12:23"
val formatter_datetime = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm")
val parsed = formatter_datetime.parse(datetimestring)
val date = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime())
val now = Calendar.getInstance
val duration = now.getTime() - date.getTime()
val diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(duration)
val is_greater: String = if (diffInHours<=5) "1" else "0"
```

I get the compilation error in the line `val duration = now.getTime() - date.getTime()`. It says `Cannot resolve symbol -`.

P.S. I'd like to avoid using any external library like e.g. jodatime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `getTime` method returns an instance of `Date` class (and not some numerical value), you should replace:

```
val duration = now.getTime() - date.getTime()
```

with:

```
val duration = now.getTimeInMillis() - date.getTimeInMillis()
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to finally convert the value to hours use:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(miliseconds)
```